# Maven Won't Compile Java 7 with 1.7 JDK

Tags: spring, maven

I must be the anti-Maven since every time I try to use it I spend a lot of time struggling and then just give up. My latest is I can not compile Java 7 source code despite having a 1.7 JDK.

Here is the output of `mvn compile`. The interesting thing is that when I was using Maven 3.0.4, the error message said `-source 1.5` instead of `-source 1.6` with Maven 3.2.1

```
[ERROR] .../src/main/java/pox/common/ServiceResponse.java:[300,43] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[ERROR] .../src/main/java/pox/common/ServiceRequest.java:[185,43] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

As you can see I am using a recent version of Maven and Maven is using Java 1.7.

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T12:37:52-05:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_40, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_40-x64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.18-371.4.1.el5", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I think the `mvn` script is adding the `/jre` since my environment variable does not specify it.

```
$ echo -e "$JAVA_HOME\n$M2_HOME"
/usr/local/java7-x64
/usr/local/maven

$ which javac
/usr/local/java7-x64/bin/javac
```

I was writing some POJOs that I wanted to *Springify* so I decided to use Maven and found this getting started with Maven on the Spring site.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started

I copied the `pom.xml` and source from the site into my STS/Eclipse project that only contained Java source and tried to compile. STS has no problem compiling any of the source code in `src/main/java`. I can remove the code that is dependent on Java 1.7 and get Maven to compile.

Every thing I have found so far implies I do not have my `JAVA_HOME` set correctly but I am pointing to a 1.7 JDK.

Comment: Provide the POM. You almost certainly aren't setting the version there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I had a similar problem, I had a project with maven and eclipse but there were problems to compile because the default level source of maven was java 1.5 and of course my code was in java 1.6,  so i had to add the compiler plugin of maven to set the right version of my source of code, here is my configuration, so I guess you should change only the 1.6 to 1.7

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems odd that I would have to tell Maven to use the default behavior of the compiler. I had tried `maven-enforcer-plugin` and failed. I might have not done it correctly though.

Comment: The default of 1.5 for Maven is a bit strange (given that even 1.6 is past end of life) but I've been bitten by this as well. I setup a parent pom in my projects that I use everywhere that has things such as JUnit etc included as well as defaulting Java to a later version

Comment: I have maven 3.1.1, I think is not too old. But there is the problem in the version 3.2.1 that is the most recent the default seems to be 1.6, I think the maven developers don't have enough time to update it.

Comment: It may be about backward compatibility. Some users would be irritated if old POMs worked differently after an upgrade. Any default value is likely to be obsolete at some point.