# How do I get maven to recognize my jdk version?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, jetty, osx-elcapitan

I'm on OSx (El Capitain) and I have Java 8 running

```
> ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

As outlined in [this separate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32923706/2490003), I needed to my java version to maven using the maven compiler plugin.

So I added the below to `pom.xml`, using the `jdk.version` placeholder

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

However, I'm stilling getting the below error when running `mvn jetty:run`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project spark-example: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/abhishek/git/abhishek/spark-example/src/main/java/Main.java:[5,34] lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

I'm aware I could hard-code `1.8` in place of the `jdk.version`, but I feel like I've seen this used without issue in other projects.

Is there something I'm missing there, or any specific reason this doesn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: You *feel like* you've seen `${jdk.version}` used before? Perhaps you meant `${java.version}`, the standard Java system property?

Comment: Do you have `jdk.version` property set? Does it work if you specify 1.8 explcitly in your configuration? `<configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want to use the property ${jdk.version}, but it was not defined in pom.

Try to add code below in you pom.xml:

```
<properties>
  <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
</properties>
```

Please refer to [properties in pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties).

Comment: oh wow, thanks! I'm still new to how the pom works. That makes sense to me.